# How to divide the region (city) into sub-regions (sub-cities) on highcharts map

Tags: highcharts

I work on the map of the KSA,
but some geographically detailed areas exist as one main region for example the Al Hudud ash Shamaliyah region (city) is present as one region and I want to divide it into four sub-regions (cities) how can I do that?
[KSA Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiVWk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this type of map doesn't exist in the Highmaps map collection - https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/.

- however, you should be able to create it by yourself: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/create-custom-maps
- or you can report this idea on Highcharts userVoice channel: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api

Have you considered to leave this region as it is and add a city just as a marker? One of the official demos: https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/flight-routes